# Failed opening required" symfony/class-loader/ApcClassLoader.php on line 110

Tags: 8, caching

I get this error after installing a module in modules/contrib and then uninstalling and moving it to a different directory. I accidentally installed the module in the wrong place.

This is in a local BLT/Drupal-VM environment. I've tried `drush cr` and rebuilding the drupal core directory as well as nuking the vendor folder that composer installs.

Seems that the paths to the installed modules gets stored in PHP memory some how and after the move php is not picking up the changes.

Restarting apache doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 16):

Restarting php from within the VM seems to have done the trick.

`sudo service php5.6-fpm restart`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did help me to solve the same issue.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me.  I had to use " sudo /etc/init.d/php7.1-fpm restart"

Comment: Thanks, this have worked for me as well. PHP 7.2 "sudo /etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm restart"

Comment: Did the trick for me as well, using Docksal I did `fin restart cli`.